# Beamer handout option with \AtBeginSection

Tags: beamer, table-of-contents

I am using `\AtBeginSection` to produce a table of contents for my Beamer presentation that appears at the beginning of each section. However, when I pass the `handout` option to beamer to make a copy of slides for my class to print the ToC slide disappears from the output.

Is there a way to maintaint the `\AtBeginSection` output at the start of each section while also producing handouts with one frame per PDF page?

Here's a MWE:

```
\documentclass[handout]{beamer}

\AtBeginSection[]  
{
\begin{frame}<beamer> 
\frametitle{Outline}
\tableofcontents[currentsection]  
\end{frame}
}
\begin{document}
\section{test section}

\begin{frame}
test slide
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Why do you add `<beamer>` at all? If you only want to avoid article mode you could use another option.

Comment: @TeXnician Oh wow, i hadn't even noticed the `<beamer>` part was there. The `\AtBeginSection` stuff is just something I copied from the web 10 years ago and have been using it ever since. Indeed, removing `<beamer>` produces the desired result. Thanks!

Comment: @TeXnician Would you like to add an answer?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You are using the following line:

```
\begin{frame}<beamer>
```

which says that the frame should only be shown in beamer mode, which does not include the `handout`. If you want it to be visible on a handout, remove that specification.

Note: If that is to prevent the frame from being printed in article mode you can add another specification.